# The sample numbers will not be equal in the Ultimate Thread Group in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

i want to explain with a simple example.

there are 4 samples and 20 users. (rampup time 10 seconds.)

after test is finished :

in standart thread group test, the numbers will be;

sample1(or request1) = 20 times

sample2 = 20

sample3 = 20

sample4 = 20

but in ultimate thread group test;

sample1 = 43

sample2 = 34

sample3 = 25

sample4 = 23

so, the number of the samplers are not equal that is a big problem for me. because sampler1 is login sample, sample4 is logoff sapmle. especially these two must be equal!!

**the problem is not related with time values. i changed the initial delay, hold load for and shutdown time but the issue wont be changed.**

if there is a way that all sampler numbers will be equal in jmeter, please tell us.

in standard thread group provide this equality but ultimate thread group doesnt.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> especially these two must be equal

not necessarily.

Ultimate Thread Group executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down so when the "Hold Load For" time ends the Ultimate Thread Group shuts the threads down.

So closer the Sampler to the top - will get more executions, closer to the bottom - less executions.

If you still want to use the Ultimate Thread Group (although it should be possible to implement whatever [ramp-up](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) and/or [ramp-down](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter) logic using built-in JMeter Test Elements) but strictly limit the number of requests - put all your "samples" under the [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) configured like:

[image]

Comment: this was a good idea but if the number of the samplers is too high, for example 100, when using Throughput Controller also cant solve the problem. while the first sampler is sent 50 times, the 50th sampler will be sent 20 times and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the samplers executed and have an equal number of sampler results use the normal [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) instead of the plugin [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

There is no interface available in the `Ultimate THread Group` to set the loop count.